# Can't fit content within a child div box and automatically expand the parent

Tags: css, css-float

I have been trying to adjust a div height so it would push all other content below it gracefully and with out overlapping, without any success.

I have two message box where each one of them is inside a wrapper ( timeslot ) div that works as a container for each.

I have tried setting the floating on the timeslot, and clearing what afterwards without success

I have tried setting `min-height` and `display: block;` without success either

```
<div class='timeslot'>
   <div class='message'>
      <span class='header'>Header text</span>
      <span>Some really long long text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The goal is trying to fit everything within the boxes and push things around nicely.

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nawar/qjDPp/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to have the `#message` to be `position: absolute`? Because that is going to remove it from the flow of the DOM, and that's why your parent element doesn't wrap around it.

Comment: Coulnd't you just `float` it? [quick edit to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/qjDPp/6/)

Comment: I tried to `float` the `.timeslot` but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go mate, I rewrote it for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/wAhnB/

```
<style>
.clear {clear:both}
.message-wrap {width:500px}
.message {width:150px; font-size:12px; background:#EDF6FB; border:2px solid #67C2EF; padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}
.message, .circle, .message-time {float:left; margin-right:20px}
.message-time {background:#F9F9F9; padding:5px; width:150px}
</style>

<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

<div class="message-wrap">

    <div class="message">
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed tortor. Integer aliquam adipiscing lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed tortor. Integer aliquam adipiscing lacus.</p>
    </div><!-- message -->

    <img class="circle" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2pt1lag.jpg" alt="" />

    <div class="message-time">
    <p><span class="date">2012-10-19</span><br />
    08:31:38</p>
    </div><!-- message-time -->

</div><!-- message-wrap -->

<br class="clear" />
<br />

<div class="response-wrap">

    <div class="message-time">
    <p><span class="date">2012-10-19</span><br />
    08:31:38</p>
    </div><!-- message-time -->

    <img class="circle" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2pt1lag.jpg" alt="" />

    <div class="message">
    <h2>Response</h2>
    <p>This is a response</p>
    </div><!-- message -->

</div><!-- response-wrap -->
```